# How to secure Neo4j browser

Tags: neo4j

Is it possible to secure the neo4j browser so users can only execute specific queries? I would like to provide generally open access to the browser, but not allow users to delete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neo4j 3.1.x security features include role based permissions. As a browser user must log in with a username and password, it is also subject to this security model.

The [authentication and authorization section](http://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/3.1/security/authentication-authorization/) of the Neo4j operations guide should be helpful to you. The [section describing native roles](http://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/3.1/security/authentication-authorization/native-user-role-management/native-roles/) already available to you gives a good visual of what is allowed per role.

It sounds like the reader native role is the one that would make sense for browser users, as deletion requires write permissions.

Finer grained permissions are possible, but based entirely upon user defined procedures, so nowhere near as simple as using the provided native roles and permissions.

However, if certain users should only be able to run a limited set of well-defined queries, then custom roles and user defined procedures should do the trick.